# RSpec renders view with incorrect escaping

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, angularjs, rspec

I'm unit testing a Rails view that uses a form builder to generalize similar code (used with an AngularJS application). While the view renders correctly in the browser, RSpec renders the view with certain characters within attribute strings incorrectly escaped: `ng: {if: "model.val < 1}"`, for example, renders as `ng-if="model.val &lt; 1"`.

### Steps to reproduce:

The form builder has a method (simplified):

```
def if_step_at_or_before(step, &block)
  content_tag :div, ng: {if: "myModel.step <= #{step}"}, &block
end
```

I use this in the view:

```
<%= f.if_step_at_or_before 3 do %>
  …
<% end %>
```

This correctly generates HTML in the browser:

```
<div ng-if="myModel.step <= 3">
  …
</div>
```

However, when I try to test this in RSpec, the tests fail (the former by saying that 1 matching element was found, the latter with 0 found):

```
before { render }

it "doesn't render with &lt;" do
  assert_select "[ng-if=?]", "myModel.step &lt;= 3", 0
end

it "renders with <" do
  assert_select "[ng-if=?]", "myModel.step <= 3", 1
end
```

Because RSpec is apparently rending the HTML with `<` escaped as `&lt;`, as in:

```
<div ng-if="myModel.step &lt;= 3">
  …
</div>
```

This did not happen when I did not use the form builder. Why is RSpec rendering views with form builders incorrectly, and what can I do to work around it?

Comment: Have you tried using [render views](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-1/docs/controller-specs/render-views) instead of render in your before block?

Comment: @yez I get undefined method error for that... according to the link, `render_views` is for controller specs, while the above is a view spec

Comment: Ah, well while `render_views` isn't working for you, I think the problem is definitely related to rendering. I'd check things like file types and making sure the rendering thinks its an html file and not something else.

Comment: It doesn't work because its for *controller* specs; this is a *view* spec...